# parse plist from sdcard in android

Tags: android, xml, plist, inputstream

In my project **parse plist from sdcard**.

I have done one example that takes a xml file from resource belove code.

```
 Resources res = activity.getResources();
 XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myplist);
```

*but i want to*

```
     XmlResourceParser xpp = (SDCARD xml file)
```

1. how to solve my problem ,so many try but i am not able to solve my
   problem ,

**Please ,Help me** .

Comment: you can improve your accepted rate to attract more SO users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should substitute the `XmlResourceParser` with [`XmlPullParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). The first one is for parsing xml from resources folder, the latter - for parsing xml from `InputStream`. From then on you need to construct an `InputStream` from the sdcard:

```
File file = new File (path-to-your-file);
fileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

xpp.setInput(fis, "UTF-8");// or whatever encoding suites you
```

**EDIT**: BTW I am interested in the way you implemented to parse plist in android.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the java file command for your xml file on sdcard.

```
File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/example.xml");
```

and using DOM or SAX parser you can parse the data(information) from it for your application.

Thnx.

**EDIT:** parsing local xml file using Sax in android, Read XML Resources in Android, using XmlResourceParser: XML parsing interface or Here or Here Look at these tutorials.